# Copy data from one worksheet to another based on column heading including empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am naïve to macros. I used below code to copy data based on column heading from sheet1 to sheet2 in same workbook. But, it stops copying when an cell is empty. Some cells in the column are empty. So, I need macro to copy entire column data including empty cells as is.

Also,  I need same kind of macro to copy between two different workbooks. I appreciate if anyone can provide macro for this.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Copy column to another workbook with matching column headers.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")
    Dim headerColumn As Long

    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Some Other Workbook").Worksheets("ws2")

    For Each header In headers
        headerColumn = GetHeaderColumn(ws2, header.Value)
        If headerColumn > 0 Then
            header.Offset(1, 0).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(1, headerColumn)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(ws2 As Worksheet, header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = ws2.Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Comment: But i need the same to work between two different workbooks

Comment: Awesome, I 'm glad I could help.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Great it works fine. It copies the data from WS1 to WS2 in another workbook. I placed button and assigned this macro in WS2, it never copied, but when I place button in WS1 it did. Is it possible to  pull data from WS1 into WS2 with a button in WS2.